# Filling area between two curves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to shade the the solid curved line and the dotted line. I tried different stuff but nothing seems to work and the problem seems relatively simple.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \draw[solid] (0,0) edge [bend right]  (1,1); 
      \draw[dotted] (0,0) --  (1,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome! Replace `edge` by `to`, and add `fill`: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
      \draw[solid,fill=blue] (0,0) to[bend right]  (1,1); 
      \draw[dotted] (0,0) --  (1,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` If you insist on using an `edge`, do `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[solid,fill=blue] (0,0) to[bend right]  (1,1) edge[dotted] (0,0); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Or `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) edge[bend right,fill=blue]  (1,1); 
 \draw[dotted] (0,0) --  (1,1); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this issue pops up rather frequently, maybe some explanation is in order. An `edge` creates a separate path. So you need either to replace the `edge` by a `to`, or use the `edge` to fill the path. Some of the options are surveyed in the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,font=\sffamily]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=only paths]
  \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) to[bend right] (1,1); 
  \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=one command,xshift=2cm]
  \draw[solid,fill=blue] (0,0) to[bend right] (1,1) edge[dotted] (0,0);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=one edge,yshift=-2cm]
  \draw (0,0) edge[bend right,fill=blue] (1,1); 
  \draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=two edges,yshift=-2cm,xshift=2cm]
  \draw (0,0) edge[bend right,fill=blue] (1,1)
   (0,0) edge[dotted] (1,1);
 \end{scope}
 \path foreach \X in {only paths,one command,one edge,two edges} 
 {(\X.north) node[above] {\X}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]