# Filling an area between 2 curves in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following tikz code as a part of a more complicated drawing with other curves using the defined coordinates.

How can I fill the area between the intersection of these compound curves?

I have some codes to fill intersection between 2 circles, but they do not apply for non-closed curves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees, overlay-beamer-styles, arrows, backgrounds, positioning, calc, intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\tikzset{lw/.style={line width=.04cm}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\coordinate (uplt) at (0,0);
\coordinate (strt) at ([shift={(-32.:4.2cm)}]uplt);
\coordinate (strtd) at ([shift={(-120.:.36cm)}]strt);
\coordinate (strtdd) at ([shift={(-148.:1.cm)}]strt);
%
\draw [very thick, blue, looseness=.88] (strtd.center) to [out=140,in=-70] node [pos=.71, circle,black, fill=black, scale=0.8](b){} +(125.:2.6cm) (strtd.center) to [out=-40,in=170] +(-24.:4.cm);
%
\draw [very thick, blue, looseness=.88] (strtdd.center) to [out=140,in=-70] node [pos=1., circle,black, fill=black, scale=0.8](a){} +(125.:2.6cm) (strtdd.center) to [out=-40,in=170] +(-24.:4.4cm);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\draw [lw, red, looseness=.8] ([shift={(45:.4cm)}]strt.center) to [out=140,in=-6] +(160.:3.2cm) ([shift={(45:.4cm)}]strt.center) to [out=-40,in=94] +(-65.:4.2cm);
\draw [lw, red, looseness=.8] ([shift={(36:.86cm)}]strt.center) to [out=140,in=-6] +(160.:3.2cm) ([shift={(36:.86cm)}]strt.center) to [out=-40,in=94] +(-65.:4.2cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at this: [Filling area between two curves in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/507218/5764)

Comment: @ Werner Thank you for your comment; but this does not answer my post. This answer fills an area between 2 curves. I need to fill only the area between the intersections of the curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `intersections` library to precisely position the nodes and the `fillbetween` library that comes with PGFPlots to fill the area between the paths. (If the latter is loaded, you don't even need to additionally load the former.)

For this to work, however, it is better to draw the paths in one go, not as two sub-paths as you do, but this can easily be achieved by reordering some values in your code.

By the way, you don't need to add `center` as anchor to a coordinate since it has no shape.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} % includes intersections library

\tikzset{lw/.style={line width=.04cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]

\coordinate (uplt) at (0,0);
\coordinate (strt) at ([shift={(-32:4.2)}]uplt);
\coordinate (strtd) at ([shift={(-120:.36)}]strt);
\coordinate (strtdd) at ([shift={(-148:1)}]strt);

\draw[very thick, blue, looseness=.88, name path=curveA] 
    (strtd) +(125:2.6) to[out=-70, in=140] 
    (strtd) to[out=-40, in=170] +(-24:4);
\draw[very thick, blue, looseness=.88] 
    (strtdd) +(125:2.6) to [out=-70, in=140] 
    (strtdd) to[out=-40, in=170] +(-24:4.4);

\draw[lw, red, looseness=.8, name path=curveB] 
    ([shift={(45:.4)}]strt) +(160:3.2) to[out=-6, in=140] 
    ([shift={(45:.4)}]strt) to[out=-40, in=94] +(-65:4.2);
\draw[lw, red, looseness=.8] 
    ([shift={(36:.86)}]strt) +(160:3.2) to[out=-6, in=140] 
    ([shift={(36:.86)}]strt) to[out=-40, in=94] +(-65:4.2);

\path[name intersections={of=curveA and curveB}]
    (intersection-1) node[circle, black, fill=black, scale=0.8] (a) {}
    (intersection-2) node[circle, black, fill=black, scale=0.8] (b) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[green, intersection segments={of=curveA and curveB, sequence={R2 -- L2}}] 
    -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Filling the area between the other two curves needs a small tweak. Note that they seem not to intersect at the upper left coordinate which is why you cannot place a node using `intersections` there. Maybe you need to adjust the curves a bit.

If you wonder how to use the `intersection segments` and `sequence` options, have a look at the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Chapter 5.7. (in version  1.18.1 of the manual) discusses the `fillbetween` library.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{lw/.style={line width=.04cm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\coordinate (uplt) at (0,0);
\coordinate (strt) at ([shift={(-32:4.2)}]uplt);
\coordinate (strtd) at ([shift={(-120:.36)}]strt);
\coordinate (strtdd) at ([shift={(-148:1)}]strt);

\draw[very thick, blue, looseness=.88, name path=curveA] 
    (strtd) +(125:2.6) to[out=-70, in=140] 
    (strtd) to[out=-40, in=170] +(-24:4);
\draw[very thick, blue, looseness=.88, name path=curveB] 
    (strtdd.center) +(125:2.6) to [out=-70, in=140] 
    (strtdd.center) to[out=-40, in=170] +(-24:4.4);

\draw[lw, red, looseness=.8, name path=curveC] 
    ([shift={(45:.4)}]strt.center) +(160:3.2) to[out=-6, in=140] 
    ([shift={(45:.4)}]strt.center) to[out=-40, in=94] +(-65:4.2);
\draw[lw, red, looseness=.8, name path=curveD] 
    ([shift={(36:.86)}]strt.center) +(160:3.2) to[out=-6, in=140] 
    ([shift={(36:.86)}]strt.center) to[out=-40, in=94] +(-65:4.2);

\path[name intersections={of=curveA and curveC}]
    (intersection-1) node[circle, black, fill=black, scale=0.8] (a) {}
    (intersection-2) node[circle, black, fill=black, scale=0.8] (b) {};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[yellow, intersection segments={of=curveB and curveD, sequence={R1 -- L1[reverse]}}] -- cycle;
    
    \fill[green, intersection segments={of=curveA and curveC, sequence={R2 -- L2}}] -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht   Thank you very much for your answer.
Just one more request. I tried to apply your code to fill the area in this picture (between the other 2 curves, instead of the area in my post)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/50hNn.jpg
, to make another drawing; but I failed to edit your code. Would you please update your answer to include this addition.

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht Thank you very much for your answer update. I appreciate it very much.